# Debugging Flutter with two devices running

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-debug

I've started two emulators and I am trying to run a Flutter app in debug mode but it won't allow me because there's the second emulator open.

I actually need the second emulator, as I've converted an Android app into Flutter and I need to debug each method step by step in both apps to see where the differences are.

Any ideas ?

This is from the Console. I've yet to start the debugger on the Android app. Can't even start the Flutter one for now ...

```
Launching lib\main_dev.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error waiting for a debug connection: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator
  Command: C:\Users\mandr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:33729
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86 64.
```